# \newtheorem just number, no name

Tags: numbering

I searched this problem for two hours and couldn't find anything.

I am writing some mathematical stuff with theorems like "Definition, Satz, Bemerkung". Now I just want to list some characteristics of a function, for example the derivation. So I want only the number of the theorem, no name!

I hope you can understand what I mean...

I uploaded a picture to make it more clearly. There you see the (17.3) is wihtout a name contrary to (17.4) with the name "Satz".

Thank you already for your help!

I [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We prefer full examples, but I think, you mean `\label{meintollersatz}` after `\begin{satz}` and refer to it with `\ref{meintollersatz}`   (Or whatever you called your 'Satz' theorem). Or do you just want to omit the `Satz` as lead-in?

Comment: Can you add the code that defines the present result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}

\newtheoremstyle{dotless}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{ }{} %get rid of the
                                %dot after the thm number

\theoremstyle{dotless}
\newtheorem{numb}{}[section]

\renewcommand{\thenumb}{(\thesection.\arabic{numb})}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{numb}
  F\"ur alle $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ gilt $\exp(k)=e^k$.
\end{numb}


\end{document}
```